# Bluetooth responses sync error Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth, titanium, response

I want to capture some responses data after I send some data via bluetooth. But I have a problem at the time of capturing the data. I send "a" into my bluetooth module and expect a response of 1 or 0. But there is an error on the part of the catch which sent the data and giving me answer a previous response.

For example:

Correct

```
App                            Bluetooth                             App
Send "a"          ===>         get "a"         must response 1 but   NULL
Send "b"          ===>         get "b"         must response 0 but   1   
Send "a"          ===>         get "a"         must response 1 but   0
```

Capturing taking a previous data!!! Please Help!

Here are the codes:

```
var ilu1= Ti.UI.createButton({
  width : Ti.UI.FILL,
  height : '80dp',
  shadowColor: '#000',
  hadowOffset: {x:0, y:0},
  hadowRadius: 2,
  font:{
    fontSize:55,
    fontFamily: customFont2
  },
  textAlign : Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
  verticalAlign : Titanium.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_BOTTOM,
  title : 'L',
  color : '#fff',
  backgroundColor:'#005a93',
  backgroundSelectedColor: '#1f2d46', 
  backgroundFocusedColor: '#1f2d46', 
  touchEnabled: true, 
    zIndex:2
});

ilu1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  novarumbluetooth.sendData('a');
  actualizalabel.text = 'Actualizando';
  var responsebtilu = novarumbluetooth.addEventListener('nb_onReceiveData', function(e)
  {        
    Ti.App.responsebt2 = e.data;    
  });
  alert(Ti.App.responsebt2);
  if (Ti.App.responsebt2=='1') {
    ilu1.title = 'K';
    actualizalabel.text = 'Actualizado';
  } else {
    actualizalabel.text = 'Error';
  };    
})
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What's `Ti.App.responsebt2`? If it is a button, shouldn't it be `Ti.UI.responsebt2`?

Comment: Ti.App.responsebt2 is a global var,I need this variable to process this event outside